# How to change the cookbooks default directory

Tags: chef-infra, knife

When I create my cookbooks using the knife command I would like them to get saved into a specified directory.
I know I can use the -o flag and specify the directory. However, I would like to make a specified directory a default directory. Is there a setting that I can change to accomplish that?
THank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify default directory under knife.rb file by inserting the following code

```
cookbook_path [
  '/your/cookbook/default_directory'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The cookbook_path parameter in knife.rb can be used to specify the default cookbook directory.